# Nested / Multiple IsBlank -

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I am trying to calculate net workdays between date of approval and last date of delivery. Problem is that the delivery is done multiple times therefore time has to be from the date of approval and the last date of delivery.

Eg.

A1-Is the Order Date

B1-First date of delivery

C1-Second date of delivery

D1-Third date of delivery

E1-Fourth date of delivery

F1-Fifth date of delivery

```
=IF((ISBLANK(F1),Networkdays(A1,E1),Networkdays(A1,F1)))
```

How do I nest this formula

Comment: Short answer to _How do i nest this formula_ is - Don't.  Instead, use Max to get the last delivery date.

Comment: can you give a screenshot of your data structure? give an example that shows what you have and what you expect to have.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy @chris neilsen. Maybe:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A2,MAX(B2:F2))-1
```

where for latest delivery date equal to order date the result is `0`.

The option to exclude holidays from the count of days may be useful and [NETWORKDAYS.INT](https://support.office.com/en-SG/article/NETWORKDAYSINTL-function-93fd60b6-ccde-4561-89bd-1be99564aa39) may be more appropriate for some locations.